# Show message when cd into specific directory

Tags: shell, cd-command

How can I display a message when I `cd` into a specific directory? This directory is a local one, and I just need a reminder when I go into it from the terminal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I were you, I would toy around with something like that in my shell configuration file (e.g. `~/.bashrc`):

```
reminder_cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && { [ ! -f .cd-reminder ] || cat .cd-reminder 1>&2; }
}

alias cd=reminder_cd
```

This way, you can add a `.cd-reminder` file in each directory you want to get a reminder for. The content of the file will be displayed after each successful `cd` to the directory.

```
gim@tenebreuse ~/tmp % echo 'warning: this directory is pure junk' > .cd-reminder
gim@tenebreuse ~/tmp % cd ..
gim@tenebreuse ~ % cd tmp
warning: this directory is pure junk
gim@tenebreuse ~/tmp %
```

Comment: Cool idea by the way! I like it, and maybe I'll use it too :-)

Comment: Not importat in this case, but in general is good abit to always double quote `$@`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now wondering if there is any case where `$@` should be preferred over `"$@"`…

Comment: You should use `$@` or `$*` (they are the same thing when unquoted) when you want IFS wordsplitting to occur.

Comment: If you use this method don't forget to alias `pushd` and `popd` also.

Comment: Now can you make it look for a `.cd-reminder` anywhere in the directory tree above the cwd and print it?

Comment: @davemyron that's already the case, as it replaces the default `cd` now to use `rebuilder_cd` when you type `cd`, so it executes the code every time you use the `cd` command